# Qt/QML Focus with Nested Views

Tags: qml, qt6

I have a `StackView`. In that I open a `SplitView`. The `SplitView` contains two parts. In one part I have a `TextField`.

When I open the `SplitView` the focus shall be put on the `TextField`.

I tried many things: `focus:true` or `forceActiveFocus()`. I have no ideas anymore. Maybe someone could give me a hint.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please provide a [mre].

Comment: If you are doing a `forceActiveFocus`  from `Component.onCompleted` it's probably too early. You want to delay it. Usually `Qt.callLater()` does the trick.

Comment: @StephenQuan and where? In the most inner view?

Comment: As per JarMan's comment, your question needs to be edited to include some code to convey better your question. Then, it will be obvious whether `Qt.callLater()` is applicable, and/or other alternate answers may be given. As it stands, the only thing we can do is supply comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    Qt.callLater(correctFocus)
}

function correctFocus () {
    callTextField.forceActiveFocus();
}
```